# unsuccessful build of a java program with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I have written a java program in Netbeans. In this program I've used extra libraries like iTextPDF. When I click the "clean and build button, the program's jar file is created in the specified path. Everything works well when I open the jar file on the path it was created. But when I copy it to another place like desktop, one of my JFrames doesn't show up when I click on the defined button.

How can I solve it? It's really wired.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the libraries aren't packaged into the build, in the properties of your project go to Build -> Packaging and make sure "Copy Dependent Libraries" is checked.

Comment: It's checked...
BTW, the JFrame which doesn't show up, is the JFrame that I have used iTextPDF in.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your extra libraries in a folder (say lib ) inside your project and then add those libraries in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Create new folder for libary in Project folder and add libraries to this new folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the "dist" folder along your jar file, a folder named "lib" also appears. You should copy that folder wherever you copy the jar file.